# How to Passing and show form variables from 1st page to 3rd page without session

Tags: php, variables

I need to pass and show variable from page one to third page how do I make it?
I mean i have 3 pages (sign_up.php, personal.php, full_detail.php).
**for Example:**

1. In sign_up.php page i have username, email, ect,..
2. And personal.php page i have address,city,state, ect ,..
3. Finally i want to show 1st page values and 2nd page values in full_detail.php.

**Note:**
 - i did one page to next.
 - how can i to pass variable from 1st to second page and same value to 3rd page.

Thank you for advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Using POST/GET**

Do it like this- If you don't want to do it using session.

**GET**

Using Anchor Tag `<a>` on first page sign_up.php write this-

```
<a href="personal.php?var1=value1&var2=value2">Personal Page</a>
```

Use header function for simply redirecting the php page to another page like this-

```
header("Location: personal.php?var1=value1&var2=value2");
```

**POST**

Also you can use HTML  Tag to send data from one page to another like this-

```
<form action="personal.php" method="post">
  <input type="hidden" name="var1" value="value1"/>
  <input type="hidden" name="var2" value="value2"/>
  <input type="submit" value="Personal Page">
</form>
```

Now on 2nd page i.e., personal.php in your case.

Catch these values like-

In case of GET Method:

```
$variable1 = $_GET['var1'];
$variable2 = $_GET['var2'];
```

In case of POST Method:

```
$variable1 = $_POST['var1'];
$variable2 = $_POST['var2'];
```

Comment: ya i did this, how to pass this values to 3rd page ?

Comment: use the same method for passing values to 3rd page or post your code here so that we can check if there is any error in your code...

Answer (score 0):

You can either send a `POST` request to the server on each step and then save the data in the session variable like so:

```
<?php
session_start();
$_SESSION['my_field'] = $_POST['my_field'];
?>
```

Or, and I would recommend this, you use javascript or a framework like jQuery to hide and show certain parts of your form. That would mean that you have all 3 parts on one PHP page and you only post to the server once.

Answer (score 0):

**By POST or GET**

You can submit the form from one to next

- Submit 1st form from 1st page to second page
- keep all the form data in hidden fields on second page and submit second form to third. with all the values from 1st page and second page
- use all the form data from 1st and second page on third page

this was you wont be needing a `session`

Comment: make sure all your form tag has proper action link and method as `get` or `post`.

Comment: am using post method both forms

Comment: if your form is submitting on second page then put a `<?php print_r($_POST); ?>` to check if you received any post data

Comment: $user = $_POST['username'];                                                            <input type="hidden" name="username" value="<?php echo $user ?>" /> i check this it work

Comment: but how to pass 3rd page

Comment: user3851915 - See my answer for better clarification.

Answer (score 0):

You can use hidden input boxes. E.g., you send the first page's values using a POST request, you can add the values like this (within your `<form>`) to your second page:

```
<?php
foreach ($_POST as $key => $value)
   echo '<input type="hidden" name="'.htmlentities($key).'" value="'.htmlentities($value).'">';
?>
```

So all values are added to your second page's form without showing them.

Be careful: If you are sending a password from page 1 to page 2, you shouldn't do it this way. In this case a session would be strictly recommended.

Comment: You are welcome. (If you are using GET, i.e. the parameters are shown in your URL, you have to replace $_POST by $_GET.)

Comment: yes Andre i know different between GET and POST Thank You

Answer (score 0):

If you want form validation then do POST method and send your variables to desired page. But if you wants to send the variables from the page where they are posted to another then I know what that is cookies..

Answer (score 0):

do this on both pages:
**signup.php**

```
<form action='full_detail.php' method='POST'>
<input type='text' name='username'>
<input type='email' name='email'>
<input type='password' name='password'>
<input type='submit' name='submit' value='Sign up'>
</form>
```

**On personal.php**

```
    <form action='full_detail.php' method='POST'>
    <input type='text' name='address'>
    <input type='text' name='city'>
    <input type='text' name='state'>
    <input type='submit' name='submit1' value='Send'>
    </form>
```

Now you can receive your variables on the third page... Echo them out...

**On full_detail.php**

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit'] || isset($_POST['submit1']))
{
echo all of your variables the simplest way.. You can pass them through url too

}
```